# Compressing a String by Unique Words

Tags: java

I have a problem where I was required to compress a string by using the index of the first unique words in a lossless style like so:

Starting String: ANY SENTENCE WHICH HAS DUPLICATES
Output after Compression: LIST OF POSITIONS OF WORDS RELATIVE TO UNIQUE WORDS

I searched for a solution online after many attempts at creating the code for myself. I could not find anything like it.

Comment: Using a LinkedHashSet, you can remove duplicates and preserve order

Comment: @cricket_007 how and where would I implement this. I just tried adding one but how would I use this for the for() loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to data processing questions like this, the Stream API is very powerful and concise.

```
String words = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";
// create a dictionary
Map<String, Integer> lookup = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// go through each word
String code = Stream.of(words.split(" "))
         // lookup the code for that word, or add one as needed
        .map(w -> lookup.computeIfAbsent(w, k -> lookup.size() + 1))
         // turn the codes into Strings
        .map(Object::toString)
         // join them together as one String.
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
System.out.println(code);
// dump the dictionary.
lookup.forEach((w, c) -> System.out.println(c + "=" + w));
```

prints

```
12345678913967845
1=ASK
2=NOT
3=WHAT
4=YOUR
5=COUNTRY
6=CAN
7=DO
8=FOR
9=YOU
```

You can extend this example to allow for 36 words

```
String words = "Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. " +
        "A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked. " +
        "If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers, " +
        "Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?";
Map<String, Integer> lookup = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String code = Stream.of(words.split("([.,?] *| +)"))
        .map(w -> lookup.computeIfAbsent(w, k -> lookup.size() + 1))
        .map(c -> Integer.toString(c, 36))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
System.out.println(code);
lookup.forEach((w, c) -> System.out.println(Integer.toString(c, 36) + "=" + w));
```

prints

```
1234567895678123a12345678bc5678123
1=Peter
2=Piper
3=picked
4=a
5=peck
6=of
7=pickled
8=peppers
9=A
a=If
b=Where's
c=the
```

Comment: @KieranEvans Indeed, it's generally a bad idea to give an answer a student can pass off as their own homework, at least you will have to learn something to do that.

Comment: @cricket_007 the code would work for up to 36 unique words with one letter codes.

Comment: I understand now.  0-9a-z

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct, but if you don't want to deal with maps and such, here is more basic approach to your problem:

```
String str = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";
String[] words = str.split("\\s+"); // Create a string array of the words in the string by splitting them around whitespace
ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();
uniqueWords.add(words[0]);
String result = "1";
boolean thereAlready = false; // Flag to be set if a word is not unique
for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) { // Iterate through every word
    thereAlready = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < uniqueWords.size(); j++) { // Iterate through previously found words to see if it matches
        if (words[i].equals(uniqueWords.get(j))) { // If the word is already there, modify the result string accordingly, set the flag, and break out of the inner loop
            result += (j + 1);
            thereAlready = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!thereAlready) { // If the word is new, add it to the found words and modify the result string accordingly
        uniqueWords.add(words[i]);
        result += uniqueWords.size();
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `12345678913967845`

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do that would be to define a Hashmap with the key being the word in question, and the value being the map index.

```
Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
// Build the dictionary of strings
for(String word : arrWords) {
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    if (!dictionary.contains(word)) {
        // Insert the word into the map.
        dictionary.put(word, dictionary.size());
    }
}
```

After that. you can just print out the map for the 'key' file:

```
// Print the dictionary
for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : dictionary.entrySet()) {
    String line = entry.getValue() + ":" + entry.getKey();
    print it somewhere...
}
```

Finally, you can print the words by looking them up in the map:

```
for(String word : arrWords) {
    print dictionary.get(word) + " ";
}
```

The dictionary will not be printed in numerical order.  I'll leave you to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, I was struggling on this as well.

:P XD

cheers ATB,

Doe Nut.